# TypeError: userData.map is not a function even though userData is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am quite new to react and trying to fetch data from a .json file (called userData.json), but .map is not working even though userData is an array.

I already checked this by doing

```
 console.log(Array.isArray(userData));
console.log(typeof userData);
```

and it's giving back 'true' and 'object'.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Here is the whole code snipped:

```
import React from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

class JsonTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: [],
      error: undefined
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("../data/userData.json").then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          userData: result
        });
      },
      error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { userData } = this.state;
    console.log(Array.isArray(userData));
    console.log(typeof userData);
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Foto</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Kategorie</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Kontaktinformation</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Job</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Notiz</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {userData.map(row => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.image}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.category}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.contactInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.job}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.note}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default JsonTable;
```

Comment: What is `result` ?

Comment: Haven't used fetch in my life, however apparently, you are fetching json. Shouldn't you use some `.json()` method to convert json to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but .map is not working even though userData is an array.

No. `render()` gets called two times. At the first time, the initial state gets rendered, `userData` is an empty array and you come to the conclusion that `userData` is an array. This time, mapping won't fail. Now the data gets fetched, and you call `setState` with `userData` being a response object (thats what `fetch()` resolves to), this time, `Array.isArray` will return `false` (but you somehow haven't seen that), and `.map` doesnt exist.

To parse the result of the `fetch` call and get an array, use `.json()`:

```
 fetch("../data/userData.json")
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(result => /*...*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you forgot to extract the`json` body?

```
fetch("../data/userData.json")
  .then(
     (result) => result.json()
  )
     .then((userData) => {
        this.setState({
           userData,
        });
     })
```

Another thing - just in case - I would secure the possibiity that `userData` is not an array.

```
{Array.isArray(userData) && userData.map(row => { ... } }
```

Comment: `json()` returns a promise?

Comment: @JonasWilms Yep, you're right. Forgot about the second `then`.

Comment: About the second part: I would rather make that `setState` neber gets called with a non array `userData`.

Comment: @JonasWilms That's rather a hint, for posterity